# Need a JSON parser for Unity3d

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I need to deserialize some JSON objects. I tried to use Tiny-json library, but it's too slow. I tried to use Newtonsoft.Json, but it fails in webplayer with this error:

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection.
```

What JSON parser do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of these open source solutions:

- https://github.com/jacobdufault/fullserializer
- https://github.com/mtschoen/JSONObject (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/710) I am using this one most of the times, it's versbose but does its job well, not sure about performance however

Or go with paid ones:

- https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11347

Answer (score 2):

**Unity 5.3** added **Native** support of Json Serializer. It is faster than others.

`JsonUtility.ToJson` to convert a class to Json.

`JsonUtility.FromJson` to convert Json back to class.

For complete example and information regarding json arrays, see

[Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/deserialization-of-json-using-minijson-in-unity-c-sharp/36244111#36244111)

Comment: It has some limitations but should do in most case. Main limitation is if your json has an array as top object then JsonUtility fails to parse.

Comment: @fafase. I mentioned that when I said "json arrays" and the array limitation problem is solved in the link I posted above.The post contains 2 answers. 1 = normal json and 2 = array json. I see no need to re-post the long solution over and over again when the-same question is asked.

Comment: I use Unity 5.2.3p3. It`s not contains JsonUtility

Comment: I mentioned in my answer you need **5.3**. All you have to do is Update to 5.3....

Comment: Also keep in mind that JsonUtility does NOT support an array of arrays (even if it's not a top level object).

Comment: @Squeazer It does **not** out of the box but **can** be made to support json array. See the link in my answer.

Comment: @Programmer As far as I can see, your answer only works for top level arrays. In my case I want to deserialize (and serialize) a GeoJSON object, which has a property that is an array of arrays ("coordinates"). Is this possible? Example: http://geojson.io/#id=gist:anonymous/1ab40fbd7911ee2fbcc8905815e0c838&map=19/46.55743/15.63705

Comment: It can't de-serialize `List<List<double>> coordinates;`. On the linked queation, go to the part where it says *"3.De-serializing Json with numeric properties"*.  It talked about `SimpleJSON.cs` which might work.